# jQuery Child Event Handling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a container element. The element may or may not have anchor tags in it. I want to listen for click events within that element. I want to handle each click only once, but I want to do something different if an anchor tag is clicked.

Issues that I've run into:

- Listening at the container element level doesn't capture the anchor tag clicks: `$('#ID').on('click', myFunction);`
- Listening to every child in the container ends up firing multiple events: `$('#ID').find(*).on('click', myFunction);`

How do I accomplish this?

Comment: Please provide a complete example with markup and a http://jsfiddle.net/ demo. The first one should capture clicks on *any* element.

Comment: Something around these lines? http://jsfiddle.net/2vpGr/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
$('#ID').on('click', function(e) {
    if ($(e.target).closest("a").length) {
        anchorWasClicked();
    } else {
        somethingElseWasClicked();
    }
});
```

Comment: I'd forgotten about the `target` attribute of the event. This works great except when there's a child element in the anchor tag: `img`, `span`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can check the `target` of the `click`. And as you seem to be trying to enable the `click` just once for every element within the container, you should then use `.one()`:

```
$(function() {
    $("#container").children().one("click", function(e) {        
        e.preventDefault(); // For testing purposes.
        
        if ($(e.target).parents().is("a") || $(e.target).is("a")) {
            // Anchor.
        }
        else {
            // Others...
        }
    });
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2vpGr/2/)

That's an improvement to the example I've posted in the comments previously.

Comment: The suggestion given by @LucasTrzesniewski could go in the `if` conditional: `$(e.target).closest("a").length`. It's simpler. Good spot.

Comment: Thanks! I accepted @LucasTrzesniewski's answer, as he got it in earlier.

Comment: That's OK. I was just trying to help. But what about the "I want to handle each click only once"?

Comment: Selector two in my example fired multiple events, and I knew that if I went that route, I'd have to ignore all but one of them.